# Im in desperate need of someone properly translating this sentence

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

"Into the furnace they tossed his soul." I've tried several different translation tools, but it always seems to change with each program. Can anyone please translate this to Latin? I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to the site. What meaning are you trying to convey with that sentence, and what do you intend to do with the phrase once it is in Latin? This context can lead to a better translation. Word-for-word translations aren't always the best way to go from one language to another.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I should have been clearer instead of just throwing the question up there like its reddit or something. I'm drawing a picture of a man being tossed into a Furnace by "fate" and I want those words or the meaning behind it above the drawing. Its done in ink so before I ruined it I wanted to be absolutely sure of the translation from English to Latin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Much of what you ask should be explained, but as far as a straightforward translation, you could say:

- ***Animum in fornacem iecerunt.***

If you really need to specify *his* (if there is otherwise ambiguity), you could add *eius* after the *animum*, but it's not strictly necessary in Latin.

A couple notes, though. Automatic translation tools are notoriously bad. Don't ever trust any of them.

Second, variation is normal. There is no one way to translate a sentence. Even in English there are multiple ways a sentence can be expressed:

- Into the furnace they tossed his soul.
- They tossed his soul into the furnace.
- Those ones cast his soul into the furnace.
- They chucked his spirit into the kiln.

Etc.

"Proper translation" is just not a real thing. Especially since in English the word "furnace" corresponds to several different things in Latin (*furnus*, *fornax*, *caminus*, and *clibanus*). It's difficult for someone who doesn't naturally speak Latin to get into the nitty gritty of all the differences, but generally all would be fine unless you were describing an exact item from antiquity, and even then we might now know all the differences, or even if two or more were identical. (Compare saying "subway sandwich" and "hoagie".)

Comment: You're right, I should have explained a bit more. Ive been a long time lover of the Poem O Fortuna. Well, the translation of it along with the other poems that went hand in hand. Ive been working on a drawing that I see in my mind when I hear or read the poem. I want to draw in those words, but I dont want to put the wrong words in. I really appreciate the detailed response. You have helped me more than you know!

Comment: @Sidious The *Carmina Burana's* 'O Fortuna'? If so, that line isn't in there. If you can locate what you're referring to, I can help further. But now I'm even more confused!

Comment: @Sidious Also, if you edit all that into the main questions, others will see the edit and may be able to offer further answers.

Comment: Yes I know that line isn't in there. Its just part of my drawing. To be a little clearer, the drawing is of a man being tossed in a Furnace by "Fate", the words are my own and I wanted to make sure I wasn't putting the wrong translation in. I appreciate your help! I do have one last question for you because you've went above and beyond to help me at this point. I know that the poem was a medieval Latin Goliardic poem written sometime in the 13th century. So was this an older version of Latin? Would it still translate the same to those that know Latin now?

Comment: @Sidious I'm no Medieval Latin expert, so I don't know which word for "furnace" would have been more common then. You could probably ask a new question based on that.

Comment: Okay. Again, I appreciate all of your help. You've made this a bit easier and now I know not to put all my trust into translation tools. Thank you!

Comment: @Sidious No problem. Remember to upvote any answers (here and of course if you ask more) you find helpful and if an answer "solves your problem" make sure to check the green check mark to mark it solved. Let me know if you have any further questions on that.